# how to update model's object in each loop

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I tried to update each object in my model within a each loop

I wanna add `size` property to each object in the model.

But it seems doesn't work.

### CONSOLE (it didn't work after I appended size property)

```
self.model().get(i).size=123
>> 123

self.model().get(i)
>>
id: 1
name: "URL_Command_Comparison"
rounds: 2
team: "cvt"
__proto__: Object
```

### CODE

```
  model: function(){
    return Ember.A([
      {id: 1, name: 'URL_Command_Comparison', 
        team: 'cvt'
      },
      {id: 2, name: 'Auto Test',
        'manualHours':20 ,'autoHours': 3, 
      ....
$.each(this.model(),function(i,d){
  self.model().get(i).set("size",self.perRoundROI(d)*d.rounds*d.coverage)
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve..Are you trying to update the `size` property of each `Ember.Object` in an array ?

Comment: Are you looking for [something like this ?](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jeqiqakituhi/1/edit?js,output)

Comment: yes. but it is only one object, my case is objects in a array

Comment: So [this should be what you are looking for](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tanarunaxemi/1/edit?html,js,output). Please let me know so I'll provide an answer with links to the documentation

Answer (score 2):

Firstly the model hook probably should never be called by you (`this.model()`).  It's called by the router when it's building up the context for the current url/transition.   If you want to access the model from the route after the transition has completed you can use `this.currentModel`.  If you want to access it somewhere else in the pipeline of the transition it is generally passed in to the common hooks (`afterModel`, `setupController`). http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_afterModel  If you want to access it from a deeper nested route, you can use `this.modelFor('foo')` where `foo` is the other route's name.

In your particular case, I'd wrap your objects in an Ember Object and create a computed property that calculates that for you.  The cool thing about that, is if you change any of the other properties that the computed property depends on, it will recalculate.

#### Object

```
App.CoolObject = Em.Object.extend({
  size: function(){
    return this.get('rounds') * this.get('coverage'); // or whatever it is you want here
  }.property('rounds', 'coverage')
});
```

#### Route

```
model: function(){
    return Ember.A([
      {id: 1, name: 'URL_Command_Comparison', 
        team: 'cvt'
      },
      {id: 2, name: 'Auto Test',
        'manualHours':20 ,'autoHours': 3, 
      }]);
},

setupController: function(controller, model){
  model = model.map(function(item){
    return App.CoolObject.create(item);
  });
  this._super(controller, model);
}
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nupoko/1/edit